# jq select value from array where json does not have any root element

Tags: json, jq

jq select value from array

```
[
{
        "fileName": "FOO",
        "md5": "blablabla"
    }, 
{
        "fileName": "BAR",
        "md5": "alaldlafj"
}
]
```

How to use JQ to select filename ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both filenames:

```
.[].fileName
```

But there are many other possibilities ...